# Mysql NOW() is not updating the db

Tags: php, mysql

I've following query which updated the db table **parkings** to **column name** : **latitude, longitude, parking_time and let_parked.** So It's update all the column but it's not updating the **parking_time** column with NOW(). Do you know why ?

```
if(isset($_POST["update"]) && $_POST["update"]==true)
{
    if($userid == "1")
    {   
        $parking_time = "(NOW() - INTERVAL 122 MINUTE)";        

        $results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE parkings SET latitude = '$mLat', longitude = '$mLng', parking_time = '$parking_time', let_parked = '1' WHERE locId = '$mId' ");
    }
    elseif($userid == '0')
    {
        $parking_time = "NOW() - INTERVAL 220 MINUTE"; 

        $results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE parkings SET latitude = '$mLat', longitude = '$mLng', parking_time = '$parking_time' WHERE locId = '$mId' ");
    }


    if (!$results) {  
      //header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not Update Markers! $mId'); 
      echo "coudld not update marker."  . mysql_error();
      exit();
    } 

    exit("Updated successfully Done! $userid, $mId");
}
```

Comment: take out the single quotes `'$parking_time'` to `$parking_time`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `()` from around your date value, e.g.

```
    $parking_time = "(NOW() - INTERVAL 122 MINUTE)";
```

should be

```
    $parking_time = "NOW() - INTERVAL 122 MINUTE";
```

and then remove the `'` from around where you use that datetime:

```
UPDATE [snip], parking_time = $parking_time,[snip]
                              ^--          ^-- no quotes
```

This will eventually produce

```
UPDATE ... parking_time = NOW() - INTERVAL 122 MINUTE, ....
```

instead of

```
UPDATE ... parking_time = '(NOW() - INTERVAL 122 MINUTE)' ...
```

Your version was generating a string which contained some text. But since that text was treated as a string, MySQL would **NOT** execute the `NOW() - ...` date math, so you were trying to literally set your db field value to an invalid date.